# find the parametric equation of the line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are two planes of equations:

$x+2y-z-1=0$ and $2x+y+z+4=0$

The required line is the intersection of the two planes.

What I've tried: I think I must solve the system composed of the 2 planes equations.

Let $z = t$, where $t$ is a real number. And then I will get $x$ and $y$ containing $t$.

But, if $z=t\rightarrow$ the last proportion of the parametric equation will be $z/1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $z=t$ as a free parameter (you only have two equations, so the third variable is free), you have the two equations:
$$x+2y=1+t$$
$$-2x-y=4+t$$

Solving this system of equations gives:

$$\{y=t \;\; \text{and}\;\; x=1-t\}$$

Then the parameterization you're looking for is

$$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix{1-t \\ t \\ t}=\pmatrix{1 \\0\\0}+t\pmatrix{-1 \\ 1\\1}$$

---

As per requested: Example of parameterization of a line $y+x+1=0$:

The slope of this line is $-1$ and the directional vector $r$ in $\pmatrix{x \\ y}=r_0+tr$ is given as $r=\pmatrix{1 \\ m}$, where $m$ is the slope of the line. $r_0$ is just a vector that points from the origin to any point on the line. Let's choose the point $\pmatrix{0 \\ -1}$. Then our parameterization becomes $$\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\pmatrix{0 \\ -1}+t\pmatrix{1 \\ -1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. And, finally, could you me explain how to reach the parametric equations form for the line from ax + by + c = 0 ?

Comment: @FlorinM. Think about it as a vector: You have to write it on the form $\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\overline{r_0}+t \overline{r}$. See more here (or many other places on the web): http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx

Comment: And it is okay that we isolated the variable z?

Comment: @FlorinM. Yes it is perfectly okay - the equal-signs is still true, even though we rearrange the equation a little bit :) And that is not the equation for a line, but for a plane, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: My mistake :) Sorry. Thanks, but I would appreciated a lot more if you gave a concrete example: bring x+y+1 = 0 into parametric form... But it is ok.

Comment: @FlorinM. All right, I'll include it in my answer. Just a minute or two!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35957/discussion-between-florin-m-and-lovsovs).

Comment: I do know that the parametric equations of a line are something like: x - x0 / l = y - y0 / m = z - zo / n. So the intersection of two planes ( of course, in space ) is a line but not in space, but in plane?

Comment: @FlorinM. That doesn't seem like a parametric, since there is no parameter. Look at this video that explains the vector-approach: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/vectors/v/linear-algebra-parametric-representations-of-lines 
I'm sorry, I don't have more time to explain, gotta go now!

Comment: @FlorinM. Of course, you're right - it *is* as line in space! I must have blacked out when approaching this problem! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem, thanks again for your help and tips!